# Multi-level radio buttons for only one flag option is confusing

Tags: support, design, flagging

I attempted to flag a question today. There were two radio buttons present which did **not** behave as radio buttons.

Clicking the flag question red confirmation button did nothing until a comment was put into the other textbox. However, no feedback was given to let me know that was necessary.

Combined with the inappropriate use of the radio buttons, it took me several attempts to figure out how to flag the question.

### Heading

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is the flag dialog box:

> [image: Flag dialog box]

When you select one of the flag reasons (e.g. "it needs moderator attention"), the dialog then asks you why it needs moderation attention:

- very low quality
- other reason (with a requirement to specify what's wrong)

That is, there are two levels of radio options:

1. Select the reason you're flagging the question
2. Explain why you're flagging it for that reason

This is marked by the second level of radio options being inset from the first level. Indentation is a common way to denote hierarchy.

The reason for this hierarchy is so we know why you think the post needs moderator attention. Otherwise, we don't know what we're supposed to do with the flag.

#### Addendum

The reason you don't see "very low quality" and why you see the odd, two-level-one-radio-button-each UI, is because you're flagging your own post. "Very low quality" doesn't make sense in that context, because if you think your question is very low quality, you shouldn't have asked it. :P

It's unlikely the two-level radio button system would be changed, but it should at least auto-select "Other" when there are no other options.

Comment: That's not the flag box I saw. I will post a screen shot.

Comment: @WilliamMioch It might be a rep issue.

Comment: @JoshK actually, it might be a flag weight issue

Comment: @WilliamMioch There are still two levels of radio buttons, and we still need you to fill the text box explaining why you want moderators to look at the post.

Comment: By definition a radio button is supposed to allow you to choose between two or more options. Two groups of one radio button each can be confusing for someone who has never seen your flag dialog.

Although there may be technical restrictions, if the only option is to select moderator attention and other, then there shouldn't BE any options. It should just be the text box.

And what's with the diamond symbol?

Comment: @WilliamMioch It's unlikely the hierarchy would be uncollapsed: the options available to you are based on the status of the question. It would make sense to just auto-select "Other" when "Very Low Quality" isn't available, though. The diamond symbol refers to us moderators.